# Right method to create CustomScript in Azure JSON template

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I am trying add a custom PowerShell script to an ARM template.
I have tried it in many different ways and always get an error, wrong URI, couldn't find file, or something similar. Could you guys please correct me?

So in variables I have the path to the file:

```
"CustomScriptScript": https://raw.githubusercontent.com/starwinddeploy/azure-sw-cluster/master/scripts/CustomScript.ps1
```

In the resource section I have a VM with another resource:

```
   {
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"resources": [
            {
                "name": "CustomScript",
                "type": "extensions",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', concat(variables('vmName'), copyindex(1)))]"
                ],
                "tags": {
                    "displayName": "CustomScript"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
                    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
                    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
                  "settings": {
                    "fileUris": [
                      "[concat(variables('CustomScriptScript'))]"
                    ],
                    "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ', variables('CustomScriptScript'))]"
                  }
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple problems:

1. Change `"type": "extensions"` to `"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions"`
2. Variable `CustomScriptScript` should be the URI of the ps1 file that you want to execute. It doesn't make sense to try and use it as the URI, and then in `commandToExecute` use it as the name of the script. You would need two different variables.

There may be other mistakes in your template. I would recommend starting with this template: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows/azuredeploy.json

Once you have that working, modify it to fit your needs.